# What is the start of first window in Kafka Streams/Ksqldb Time windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Kafka Streams and ksqlDB are based on the Unix epoch time in the UTC timezone. So my question is. If i define a tumbling window with window size of 5 minutes, the first windows will begin at 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970? I mean the boundaries (start and end) of a window are tied this way?
First Window    Second Window   Third Window
00:00:00 UTC -> 00:05:00 UTC -> 00:10:00 UTC -> ...

Comment: It should start the window on the first consumed event... Is that not what you're seeing?